# Xamarin.Forms: ImageSource doesn't contain definition for FromResource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm following a tutorial but when I use ImageSource.FromResource to put in the source path for the image I get an error:

> ImageSource doesn't contain definition for FromResource.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you using an old version of xamarin.forms, is declared [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1362) and you can find a temporarily solution

Edit :
after talking the problem was naming , you have created a class or property with the same name as ImageSource so using Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource instead solve the problem.

Comment: The link you've shared points to the problem where the error is thrown at runtime but in my case the project won't even compile. I tried updating my  nuget packages but I get an error: `Could not install package 'Package Name'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Comment: Can you try another picture name without space and special character

Comment: For the second problem  last Xamarin.Android.* packages requires your project to target MonoAndroid 8.0. If you change your project to target 8.0 then you will be able to install this NuGet package. you can change it from `Project Properties>Android Manifest > Target Android versions`

Comment: It's not about the name, I tried different names but still got error.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it has got something to do with the project not being able to update nuget packages, I tried ImageSource.FromResource in another solution in which the nuget packages were updated successfully, it worked there. I'm changing target Framework, Target Android version and Minimum android version back and forth to eliminate that error but still no success.

Comment: try forcing it , `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromResource("pic.png");` i think that you created class or property with the same name that's why !

Comment: Though the nuget packages still can't update Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromResource("pic.png"); is working for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`Image kjdb = new Image();
            kjdb.Source = ImageSource.FromResource()`

Comment: Not working, FromResource is not contained by ImageSource.